# Flutter: null safety updates get me some errors in code

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I have a project was made before null safety, now the code has a lot of errors
I was fixed all error except this two errors shown below, and I'm not sure what should I do about this

The first error:
[The first error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1YN.png)

===============================

The Second error:
[The Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFrEi.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If null safety is giving you errors and you wan't to disable it, you can easily do it by changing the minimum sdk constraints in the pubspec.yaml file just change sdk to ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a null-able value like `String? _token`. Because it can be a null value before initializing the value.
Or you can use a `late` keyword to init later, but you shouldn't use this before init.

For more info, reference the [Null safety in Dart video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYhOU9AuaFs).